# What is the next number in the sequence 3,0,1,6,7? And How to code this sequence up to n digits?

Tags: algorithm, sequence

Got this question in a programming test. The actual question was to compute this sequence up to nth digit and compute its sum. The question said that '3,0,1,6,7 are first five numbers of the sequence'

Comment: From your current context and sequence => [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C0%2C1%2C6%2C7&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: I think that such type of question doesn't make sense and it should not be asked anywhere. Next number can be anything you like.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple number sequence problem.
let assume : given number sequence having array order number like.

array Index :  1    2   3   4   5   6   7

logic       : +2   -2  -2  +2  +2  -2  -2

sequence    :  3    0   1   6   7   4   5 ....

if we follow zero indexing than number sequence would be 
2,3,0,1,6,7,4,5...etc
use two time addition and two time subtraction ..continue till given range.

Java Code :

```
int n=10;
int sequence[]=new int[n+1];
int i=0;
boolean flag=true;
while(i<n)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        sequence[i]=i+2;
        i++;
        sequence[i]=i+2;
    }else
    {
        sequence[i]=i-2;
        i++;
        sequence[i]=i-2;
    }
    i++;
    flag=!flag;
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    System.out.print(sequence[i]+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@mukesh-prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61300262/8702713) said its sequence of adding and subtracting +2 and -2 two times consecutively to n natural numbers.

You can code this in python as:

```
n = int(input())
sum = 0
flag1 = 0
flag2 = 0
for i in range(1,n):
    if(flag1 == 0 and flag1 == flag2):
        print(i+2, end=" ")
        sum += i+2
        flag1 = 1
    elif(flag1 == 0 and flag1 != flag2):
        print(i+2, end=" ")
        sum += i+2
        flag2 = 0
    elif(flag1 == 1 and flag1 == flag2):
        print(i-2, end=" ")
        sum += i-2
        flag1 = 0
    else:
        print(i-2, end=" ")
        sum += i-2
        flag2 = 1
print("\nSum: " + str(sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence in you programming test is really based on the +2/-2 pattern, then  it will repeat at the 5th element and, therefore, we can shorten it and apply a modulo operation to find the nth element:

```
nth_number = lambda n: n + [+2, +2, -2, -2][n % 4]
```

For the sum, we must observe that this pattern elements cancel each other during a sum and, therefore, we can also find a shortened, repeating pattern for the sum:

```
n:          1  2  3  4   5  6  7  8   9 ...
modifier: [+2 -2 -2 +2][+2 -2 -2 +2][+2 ... ]
sum:      [+2  0 -2  0][+2  0 -2  0][+2 ... ]
```

With this shortened sequence, once again we can use the modulo operation, this time assisted by the [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), to calculate the sum:

```
sum_up_to_n = lambda n: n * (n-1)/2 + [+2,  0, -2,  0][(n-1)%4]
```

This approach is O(1). Other approaches are [Pseudo-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) O(n). Code is in Python3.